# JavaFX Custom Control undesired behaviour if in controller

Tags: java, javafx-8

Previously, i posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492977/display-sales-information-in-treetableview) on how to display sales information in a tree view manner and someone gave a good answer.The problem is when implemented his answer in javafx controller, a rather undesired behavior happens where the control keeps on stretching outwards upon any event.
I have created [this](https://github.com/yunus89/javafx-custom-control.git) github repo to demonstrate both desired and undesired behaviour.

The desired behavior happens when no controller(fxml) is involved, though i use fxml in my project and i expect the custom control to behave in my controller.

## Update

Any additional information needed will be provided, just ask.